# Segmentation fault while creating QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtextedit, qtimer

I wrote a minimal example in which my application crashes. I can't figure out what's wrong. I hope someone has thoughts about the reason for this segfault.

if you increase the QTimer timeout, for example, even to 10 milliseconds, there will be no falling. Also. which is strange, if you remove a.setStyleSheet(result), everything will be fine too.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "test.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QString result;
    QFile textFile("/home/narina/workspace/CubSatPanel/ulib/src/styles/Gravira.qss");

    if (textFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        result = textFile.readAll();
        textFile.close();
    }

    a.setStyleSheet(result);

    std::unique_ptr<Test> communicator = std::make_unique<Test>();

    QThread communicatorThread;
    communicator.get()->moveToThread(&communicatorThread);
    QObject::connect(&communicatorThread, SIGNAL(started()),communicator.get(), SLOT(run()));

    MainWindow w;
    communicatorThread.start();
    w.show();

    int ret = a.exec();

    communicatorThread.exit();
    communicatorThread.wait();

    return ret;
}
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTextBrowser>

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     Test() = default;
public slots:
    void tester()
    {
        QTextEdit logTextBrowser;
    }

    void run()
    {
        m_timer = new QTimer(this);
        m_timer->setInterval(1);
        m_timer->setSingleShot(false);


        connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this,  SLOT(tester()));
        m_timer->start();
    }


private:
    QTimer* m_timer;
};
```

Comment: Is creating `QTextEdit m_logTextBrowser;` (shadowing the member) intended in `tester()`?

Comment: GUI stuff should be done in gui (main) thread only.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you appear to be creating a widget (`QTextEdit`) on a thread *other* than that on which `main` is running: that's not supported.

Comment: creating QTextEdit in tester() is Intended, I edited it.

Comment: @G.M. you got it right

Comment: @G.M. But why does the error not occur when the timer is not called so often?

Comment: Because it's essentially undefined behaviour so anything can happen -- including it 'appearing' to work every now and again.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you, I found this also in the documentation